# Setting Author Id of sharepoint list item with rest API

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I'm trying to create a new list item, but specify the created by to someone other than the account that's inserting the records, it looks like from some of the documentation it should be possible to also set the created by after the fact too, either way is fine with me, the below example is me trying to update an existing record with a new created by.

I've found an example of updating the created by from the .net API http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/03/14/can-we-update-the-values-of-created-by-modified-by-columns-in-sharepoint-lists.aspx

Everything looks like it works with this request, but the value isn't actually updated.

```
POST http://sp/site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('listtitle')/items(255) HTTP/1.1
X-HTTP-Method: MERGE
X-RequestDigest: <requestDigest>
IF-MATCH: *
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) WindowsPowerShell/3.0
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
Host: sp
Content-Length: 196

{
    "Author":  {
               "Id":  555
           },
    "__metadata":  {
                   "type":  "SP.Data.listtitleListItem"
               }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the Author field to not be read only. You can post to:
`/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('listtitle')/Fields('<createdbyguid>')`
Updating the field  `ReadOnlyField` to `false`

After that the updates to AuthorId (but not Author { Id }) will work.